# Find the tangent plane on $z=x^3-xy$ perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm not sure how to do this. I tried letting $\partial{z}/\partial{x}=1$ and $\partial{z}/\partial{y}=1$ then solving for $z$ at this point and subbing them into $x+y+z=c$ but I just get $x+y+z=0$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^3 - xy - z$. We have $\nabla f = (3x^2 - y, -x, -1)$ is a normal to the surface at each point. In particular, $\nabla f$ is a normal to the tangent plane in question. We want the tangent plane to be orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$, hence $\nabla f$ parallel to $(1,1,1)$ and it this is true iff:

$$\begin{cases} y - 3x^2 = 1 \\ x = 1 \end{cases}$$

which gives $x = 1$, $y = 4$. These correspond to the point with $z = x^3 - xy = 1 - 4 = -3$, so we get the point $(1,4,-3)$.

Therefore, the tangent plane has normal $N = (1,1,1)$ and passes through $(1,4,-3)$, so its equation is: $x - 1 + y - 4 + z + 3 = 0$, i.e. $x + y + z = 2$.

Comment: thanks, why did you use the negative of the derivatives?

Comment: @Jake you mean why did I put $y -3x^2 = 1$ and $x =1$? Because $\nabla f $ being parallel to $(1,1,1)$ implies the existence of $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ such that $\nabla f (x,y,z)= \lambda(1,1,1)$, which gives $\lambda = -1$. The equations follow by comparison

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand. why does that give $\lambda = -1$?

Comment: @Jake $\nabla f(x,y,z) = (3x^2 - y, -x,-1)$. If this is equal to $\lambda(1,1,1)$ (which is $(\lambda, \lambda, \lambda))$, then comparing the last coefficient from each vector we get $-1 = \lambda$

Comment: ah okay, I didn't see that you were using $f(x,y,z) = x^3 - xy - z$. Can you explain what the implications of this are? is it still the same surface?

Comment: @Jake in this special case, the surface is a *level surface*, which means that we can also represent it as $z = g(x,y)$. In general, any surface in $\Bbb R^3$ has an equation $f(x,y,z) = 0$, but it can't always be written as $z = g(x,y)$. The method I solved the problem with works when you are dealing with any general surface.

Answer (score 0):

[The normal to a surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) $f(x,y)$ is given by

$$ n = \left( \begin{matrix} f_x \\ f_y \\ -1\end{matrix}\right ) $$

and we have $f_x = {\partial z \over \partial x} = 3x^2 -y$ and $f_y = {\partial z \over \partial y}=-x$.

When is $ \left( \begin{matrix} 3x^2 - y \\ -x \\ -1\end{matrix}\right )$ parallel to $ \left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right )$?

Note $x$ must be $-1$ from which it follows that $y=4$ which implies $z=-3$.

So the point in question is $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (1,4,-3)$.

The equation for a tangent plane at a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by

$$ z-z_0 = f_x (x_0,y_0)(x-x_0) + f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$$

and substituting in $(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (1,4,-3)$ we get

$$ z+3 =(1)\cdot(x-1) + (-1)\cdot(y-4)$$

and moving all the variables to one side we get

$$ x+y+z=2$$

Comment: thanks, why did you check when the derivatives are parallel to $ \left( \begin{matrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ -1\end{matrix}\right )$?

Comment: @Jake That's a minor "typo" (but the answer remains correct even with the typo). That's the vector you are given. And this vector is the normal vector of the plane that you are looking for. So you want the normal vector of your plane to be parallel to it.